# What is the best way to conditionally compile under tvOS

Tags: objective-c, tvos

Given an iOS function like so:

```
+ (UIView*) aView
{
  UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
  CGRect rect = screen.applicationFrame;
  return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
}
```

This fails to compile under tvOS because UIScreen.applicationFrame is not defined. What is the best pre-processor symbol to check specifically for tvOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TARGET_OS_TV` from `TargetConditionals.h`